# How can i add a default null in Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, foreign-keys, alter-table

Hello everyone i am new to databases and i am trying to make add a foreign key the first time i tried i had the following error
`ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option` when i googled it it found something like `DEFAULT NULL:` But when i use it i get the Following error code  `RA-00904: : invalid identifier`

My alter Table looks like this

```
alter table car
add constraint priceCar DEFAULT NULL foreign key (note) references priceCode(note) DEFAULT NULL;
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong this is my first time using databases Oracle

Comment: A default value is part of the column definition, not the referential constraint; but most data types default to null anyway. Why do you think you need this; and was your searching specific to Oracle?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes spefcif to oracle and thats the first thing that showed up i am new to this i dont know to much about it

Comment: to expound on @AlexPoole's note - why do you think you need a DEFAULT NULL clause? and let's split that out from your FK constraint definition

Comment: @thatjeffsmith what else should or could i use

Comment: @user9691016 you don't need to define a default null for column - that's already there...by default. exceptions might be if you wanted to default to EMPTY_CLOB or BLOB() for zero length lobs https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions049.htm#SQLRF00636

Comment: A default value is not a constraint

Answer (score 0):

Adding the constraint would just be:

```
alter table car
add constraint priceCar foreign key (note) references priceCode(note);
```

assuming the relevant column already exists in both tables and is the same data type, and is a primary or unique key in `priceCode`.

The default value for a column is a completely unrelated issue, and as this is presumably a number column it will default to null anyway. You *can* explicitly add a default null clause to the column definition (not the constraint) but you don't need to.

Quick demo with made-up tables:

```
create table pricecode(note number primary key);

Table PRICECODE created.

create table car (id number, note number);

Table CAR created.

alter table car
add constraint priceCar foreign key (note) references priceCode(note);

Table CAR altered.

insert into car (id) values (1);

1 row inserted.
```

Then:

```
select * from car;

        ID       NOTE
---------- ----------
         1
```

shows that `note` defaulted to null without you having to explicitly set that up (and also that it didn't complain about it not matching any primary key value).